# Why does using replace to unescape html tags strips out all other html tags as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to convert `&lt;` and `&gt;` in a table to `<` and `>`. The function I'm using to do this works well.

```
<div class="schedule">    
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.&lt;br /&gt;
            <em>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</em>&lt;br /&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.table-container td').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var t = $this.text();
  $this.html(t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>'));
});
```

However, this function also removes the `<em>` tags that don't need any unescaping. Anyone know why?

https://jsfiddle.net/et1crLug/

Comment: Because you get the content with `.text()` and then use `.html()` to put the content back.

Answer (score 1):

Because you used `.text()` to get your HTML content.

Use `.html()` instead:

```
var t = $this.html();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/et1crLug/1/

Comment: Except that doesn't convert the `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Is there a way to do both?

Comment: Ah, because this: `t = t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>');` is wrong. You need to include both the `;` *and* write a `replaceAll()` method.  See https://jsfiddle.net/et1crLug/3/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut method using [html(function)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) to replace the `each` loop

```
$('.table-container td').html(function(_,existing){
     return existing.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;', '>');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/et1crLug/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

When you're using replace() i've found it only replaces the first instance. If you use regex you can set it to replace every instance of `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `/g`

https://jsfiddle.net/xdoj0qLy/